# Calling a COM object from .Net C#

Tags: c#, .net, com

I am trying to access a COM dll(eObjectBroker) from my C# application. Here are things I have done.

1. run tlbimport with `eObjectBroker.dll` to get the assembly. I get two assemblies, as `COMSVCLIB` is referenced from `eObjectBroker`. So I have `eObjectType.dll` and `COMSCVLIB.dll`
2. I add reference to these two assemblies in my .Net c# project. I also add reference to `adodb.dll` as a function call I make returns a Recordset type object.
3. I create the instance for a class in `eObjectType` and call one of its function. On this call I get the error **`Object variable or with Block variable not set`**

What have I missed? Is this the right method to access the COM dll?

Answer (score 3):

Using VS2005 and later all you have to do is add a reference to a registered (with regsvr32.exe) COM dll, create a new instance and call it's methods. I believe you would have to instatiate the main class of the COM object though and access the other parts through that interface.